# Navigation in Terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

Simple one here guys, I remember there was a key that you could press in terminal to fill out the folder name for you when changing directory, saving you have to type out a huge folder name and escaping in the spaces.

```
cd mydir/ccp... ..... .......
```

I can't find it on google, does anyone know the key/key command I'm taking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about completion? In bash (any many other shells) `Tab` is the key for completion.

Answer (score 1):

Its the `TAB` key (assuming you are using bash shell in Terminal on Mac OS X).